# How can I retrieve current user id within wordpress plugin?

Tags: users

I am developing a website in WordPress and came across with an issue, I am unable to get current user/logged user id in WordPress plugin.
below code is working while I am on a page.

```
$userID = get_current_user_id();
```

Is something wrong with the above method while using it within the plugin?

Comment: An important note, but *when* and *where* are you calling the function?

Comment: Also, WordPress.com is a 3rd party service, are you sure you meant to tag wp.com?

Answer (score 4):

You probably called it too early, `get_current_user_id` uses `wp_get_current_user`, so move all your code that's at the top level of `functions.php` into the `init` hook or appropriate equivalent. The only thing that should be in the global scope in your functions file if you want maximum compatability and efficiency is `add_action` and `add_filter` calls